# playonlinux update to 4.2.1 problem

Tags: 12.04

I have a problem I install playonlinux from the ubuntu software center and there is a new update: 4.2.1; i don't know how to get this new update, im new to ubuntu and I don't know why to get an update has to be this difficult.

please help

I saw that there is office 2010 and I will like to get it...

Comment: As the marked duplicate question indicates - this is how Ubuntu works. Packages are frozen towards a release and only get updated for critical issues or security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

PlayOnLinux have their own repository for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. It has the latest released version. As noted on their [Download page](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html):

Copy & Paste the following line-by-line in a terminal.

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```